# How to change sizing of D3 axis?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

Working within a React framework, I have a JSON data set of weights and I am trying to display on a simple number line using D3.js, where the left end is the min, the right end is the max, and a particular individuals weight is a tick with the color red.

I've coded up a solution that creates this, however I cannot for the life of me figure out how to make it larger. Here's the code, where this.state.range = [126.4, 212.2] and this.state.avg = 167:

```
var svgContainer = d3.select("body").append("svg").attr("width",500).attr("height", 200);
var axisScale = d3.scaleLinear().domain(this.state.range).range(this.state.range);
var axisBot = d3.axisBottom(axisScale);
var ticks = [this.state.range[0], this.state.range[1], this.state.avg, this.state.patient.weight];
axisBot.tickValues(ticks);
var xAxisGroup = svgContainer.append("g").call(axisBot);
d3.selectAll('g.tick').filter(function(d){ return d==186.4;} ).select('line').style('stroke','red');
```

This code produces this result:

[image: screenshot]

Can anyone please tell me how to **a) make this number line larger** and **b) how to center the line?**

I apologize if this is a bit remedial, however it is my first time working with D3.js.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code, the domain and the range are the same (assuming that `this.state.range` is an array):

```
var axisScale = d3.scaleLinear()
    .domain(this.state.range)
    .range(this.state.range);
```

You have to set the `range` according to the positions you want in your SVG. For instance, without any padding, if your SVG has a width of 500px:

```
var axisScale = d3.scaleLinear()
    .domain(this.state.range)
    .range([0, 500]);
```

So, the range goes from left border (x = 0) to the right border (x = 500).

Remember: domain refers to the input values,  while range refers to the output positions.